# Make a column based a repetitive numbers that follows another column

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence, rep

I have this data and I want to make a new column:

```
structure(list(AGE_GROUP = c("21-30", "31-40", "41-50"), DATE = c("12/17/2020", 
"12/17/2020", "12/17/2020"), VACCINE_COUNT = c(36L, 47L, 26L), 
    PERC_TOTAL_VACC = c(24.82758621, 32.4137931, 17.93103448), 
    RECIPIENT_COUNT = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), PERC_TOTAL_RECIP = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), RECIP_FULLY_VACC = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), PERC_FULLY_VACC = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

based on age group I want to make a column that includes this numbers c(8, 12,13,16,14,12), and repeat this column 3 times. So the outcome is a new column that 3times have the mentioned numbers.

I have used this code  `vaccine<-vaccine %>%  mutate(new_col = rep(list(vals), n())) %>% unnest()`
and I have something  like this

````
"12/18/2020", "12/18/2020"), VACCINE_COUNT = c(421L, 421L, 421L
), PERC_TOTAL_VACC = c(15.52932497, 15.52932497, 15.52932497), 
    RECIPIENT_COUNT = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), PERC_TOTAL_RECIP = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), RECIP_FULLY_VACC = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), PERC_FULLY_VACC = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), X = c(NA, NA, NA), X.1 = c(14L, 14L, 
    14L), new_col = c(8, 12, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```

While I want to keep my data and just repeat  the data
````

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to repeat the values `c(8, 12,13,16,14,12)` for each row in the dataframe? Try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

vals <- c(8, 12,13,16,14,12)

df %>%
  mutate(new_col = rep(list(vals), n())) %>%
  unnest(new_col)
```

Comment: Thank you , but it does not give me my expected results. Vals is repeating  for each row 6 times while I want to keep the shape of the data and  vals repeat sequence

Comment: @AliRoghani Do you mean `df %>% mutate(new_col = rep(vals, length.out = n()))` ? If not can you include your expected results in the post?

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
transform(df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), each = length(vals)),], new_col = vals)
```

---

Or with `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    uncount(length(vals)) %>% 
    mutate(new_col = rep(vals, length.out = n()))
```

---

If we need to just `rep`licate and store the column, wrap in a `list`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(new_col = list(vals))
```

#### data

```
vals <- c(8, 12,13,16,14,12)
```

Comment: Thank you , but it does not give me my expected results. Vals is repeating  for each row 6 times while I want to keep the shape of the data and  vals repeat sequence

Comment: @AliRoghani In that case, you can just keep it as a `list` column